# WSO2 ESB -How to call Iterate mediator with call blocking?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm calling an Endpoint within *Iterate mediator*, but calls are made in a parallel manner, due to which all calls are *failing except the last one*. receiving *"too many requests" error* from endpoint

I've also set `'sequential="true"'`. So I tried Call mediator with `'Blocking="true"'` then, no calls are being made to the URL. Even Tried Callout mediator then also No calls are being made

Please suggest me a solution in calling Endpoint sequentially from an Iterate mediator

```
<iterate continueParent="true" expression="//Data" sequential="true">
   <target>
      <sequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Check&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;" value="Inside Iterator" />
         </log>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"RecordID":"$1" }</format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//Data/RecordId" />
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="XXXX" scope="default" type="STRING" value="https://XXXX" />
         <property expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('XXXXX'))" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING" />
         <call blocking="true">
            <endpoint>
               <http method="post" uri-template="{uri.var.getrecordfile}">
                  <suspendOnFailure>
                     <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                     <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                  </suspendOnFailure>
                  <markForSuspension>
                     <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                  </markForSuspension>
               </http>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <log level="custom">
            <property expression="json-eval($)" name="RESPONSE &gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;" />
            <property expression="$trp:Status" name="Status" />
         </log>
      </sequence>
   </target>
</iterate>
```

Comment: when you use call mediator with blocking call, do you get any errors

Comment: No Errors, Just log stops at call mediator level and only Timeout error comes after sometime